# deep lerning number guesser with python(tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pygame

I made a deep learning number guesser with `python`(in `jupyter notebook`and I used ten)when I run the code it should open a empty window(with `pygame`) that I can draw numbers to train the deep learning but I get tow `AttributeErrors` this is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pygame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class pixel(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = (255,2555,255)
        self.neighbors = []
    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height))
    
    def getNeighbors(self, g):
        j = self.x // 20
        i = self.y // 20
        rows = 28
        cols = 28
        
        if i < cols -1:
            self.neighbors.append(g.pixels[i + 1][j])
        if i > 0:
            self.neighbors.append(g.pixels[i - 1][j])
        if j < rows -1:
            self.neighbors.append(g.pixels[i][j + 1])
        if j > 0:
            self.neighbors.append(g.pixels[i - 1][j + 1])
        
        if j > 0 and i > 0:
            self.neighbors.append(g.pixels[i - 1][j - 1])
        if j + 1 < rows and i > -1 and i - 1 > 0:
            self.neighbors.append(g.pixels[i - 1][j + 1])
        if j - 1 < rows and i < cols - 1 and j - 1 > 0:
            self.neighbors.append(g.pixels[i + 1][j - 1])
        if j < rows - 1 and i < cols - 1:
            self.neighbors.append(g.pixels[i + 1][j + 1])

class grid(object):
    pixels = []
    
    def __init__(self, row, col, width, height):
        self.rows = row
        self.cols = col
        self.len = row * col
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.generatePixels
        pass
    
    def draw(self, surface):
        for row in self.pixels:
            for col in row:
                col.draw(surface)
    
    def generatePixels(self):
        x_gap = self.width // self.cols
        y_gap = self.height // self.rows
        self.pixels = []
        for r in range(self.rows):
            self.pixels.append([])
            for c in range(self.cols):
                self.pixels[r].append(pixel(x_gap * c, y_gap * r, y_gap * r, x_gap, y_gap))
                
        for r in range(self.rows):
            for c in range(self.cols):
                self.pixels[r][c].getNeighbors(self)

    def clicked(self, pos):
        try:
            t = pos[0]
            w = pos[1]
            g1 = int(t) // self.pixels[0][0].width
            g1 = int(t) // self.pixels[0][0].width
            g2 = int(w) // self.pixels[0][0].height
            
            return self.pixels[g2][g1]
        except:
            pass
    def convert_binary(self):
        li = self.pixels
        
        newMatrix = [[] for x in range(len(li))]
        
        for i in range(len(li)):
            for j in range(len(li[i])):
                if li[i][j].color == (255,225,255):
                    newMatrix[i].append(0)
                else:
                    newMatrix[i].append(1)
        mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
        (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
        x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)
        for row in range(28):
            for x in range(28):
                x_test[0][row][x] = newMatrix[row][x]
                
        return x_test[:1]
    
def guess(li):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('m.model')
    
    predictions = model.predict(li)
    print(predictions[0])
    t = (np.argmax(predictions[0]))
    print("I predict this number is a:", t)
    window = Tk()
    window = withdraw()
    messagebox.showinfow("prediction", "I predict this number is a:" + str(t))
    #plt.imshow(li[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    #pit.show()
    
def main():
    run = True

    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                li = g.convert_binary()
                guess(li)
                g.generatePixels()
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                clicked = g.clicked(pos)
                clicked.color = (0,0,0)
                for n in clicked.neighbors:
                    n.color = (0,0,0)
                    
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:
                try:
                    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    clicked = g.clicked(pos)
                    clicked.color = (255,255,255)
                except:
                    pass
                
        g.draw(win)
        pygame.display.update()

pygame.init()
width = height = 560
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Number Guesser")
g = grid(28, 28, width, height)
main()
```

this is the output:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.8.8)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a4fa9a8a2b5c> in <module>
    149 pygame.display.set_caption("Number Guesser")
    150 g = grid(28, 28, width, height)
--> 151 main()

<ipython-input-1-a4fa9a8a2b5c> in main()
    129                 pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    130                 clicked = g.clicked(pos)
--> 131                 clicked.color = (0,0,0)
    132                 for n in clicked.neighbors:
    133                     n.color = (0,0,0)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'color'
```

Comment: `clicked = g.clicked(pos)` is retuning `None`.

Comment: Well, whatever `g.clicked()` returns is None. Maybe you should check for that before trying to access `.color` on it?

Comment: You have a bare `try: except:` in `.clicked()` – never, _ever_ use `try: except:` with no exception type chosen.

Answer (score 1):

1. `g.clicked()` is clearly returning None for you to get a `NoneType` object error when accessing the return value.
2. If we look at the `clicked()` method, we can see there's a `try: ... except: pass` construct. It means that any and all errors that might happen are just thrown out of the window, and since a function that doesn't explicitly return returns `None`, we can assume that's what happening.

   - Takeaway 1: Never, *ever* use `try: except:` like that. Just let the exception happen and handle it elsewhere.
3. Reasons why there might be *some* exception we don't know about in that function could be e.g.

   - an `IndexError` when unpacking the argument
   - an `IndexError` accessing `self.pixels`
   - a `ZeroDivisionError`
   - a `NameError` or an `AttributeError` if we've typoed something
   - anything else too, heck if we know
4. For the time being, let's look at what initializes `self.pixels`... Looks like `generatePixels` is the thing.
5. What calls `generatePixels`? Well... nothing, since the "call" to it in `grid`'s `__init__` is missing the call parentheses: `self.generatePixels` should be `self.generatePixels()`.

   - Takeaway 2: Use an IDE or linter that warns you about stuff like that.

So, tracing that back:

- `self.pixels` never gets initialized because `generatePixels` is not called.
- An exception accessing `self.pixels` is swallowed by the bare `except:`.
- You get a `None` from the `clicked()` function.
- You try accessing the `None` and you get the exception.

While there are other clear issues in the code, you might want to start by

- fixing the call to `generatePixels()`
- unwrapping `try: except:`s